# Scraping an ASPX session site with python requests, and a few redirects

Tags: python, asp.net, session, curl, cookies

I'm trying to scrape a site for an appliance that I own.  The appliance uploads its data to this site, and the site itself does not an offer an API, or any other programmatic way for me to access this data.

A successful looks like this (per browser inspection tool):

1. GET /Site/Login.
2. POST /Site/Login
3. 302 to /Site/Index
4. 302 to /Customer/Account
5. 302 to /Customer/Account/email%40domain.tld

Here's the code that I have thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import json

payload = {
    "Email" : email,
    "Password" : password,
    "Remember" : 'false'
}
headers = {
  'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',
}

s = requests.Session()

s.get('https://www.wifi.ecowater.com/Site/Login')

# Add the RequestVerificationToken to the payloay.
RVT = requests.utils.dict_from_cookiejar(s.cookies)
payload['__RequestVerificationToken'] = RVT['__RequestVerificationToken']

r = s.post('https://www.wifi.ecowater.com/Site/Login', params=payload, headers=headers)

print(r.text)
```

This code gets me an error page, almost like requests is not following all of the redirects.

Here are the `curl` commands for the 5 steps from above, per Firefox's browser inspection tool.

EDIT:  Tried posting the 5 curl commands, but stackoverflow flags this as a spam when I do so, and does not let me post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost had it in my original question, but after looking at the website a bit closer, I found a hidden form input with a second `__RequestVerificationToken`.

Essentially, I don't need to manually manage the `__RequestVerificationToken` cookie at all - `requests.Session` does that - but I do need to add the hidden `__RequestVerificationToken` to the form data payload.

We end up with two different tokens, both named `__RequestVerificationToken`.  One is sent from the server and is a cookie, the other is form data, which you need to manually find.

Here is my working code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import requests
import re

# Regex to match the hidden input on the initial log in page
request_validation_re = re.compile(r'<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="(.*?)" />')

# The serial number of your ecowater device
dsn = { "dsn": "serial" }

# The initial form data
payload = {
    "Email" : "emailaddress",
    "Password" : "password",
    "Remember" : 'false'
}

# The headers needed for the JSON request
headers = {
    'Accept': '*/*',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Accept-Language' : 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:73.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/73.0'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    # Initial GET request
    g = s.get('https://www.wifi.ecowater.com/Site/Login')

    # Grab the token from the hidden input
    tokens = request_validation_re.findall(g.text)
    # Add the token to the form data payload
    payload['__RequestVerificationToken'] = tokens[0]

    # Log in to the site
    login = s.post('https://www.wifi.ecowater.com/Site/Login', data=payload)
    # Add the correct Referer header
    headers['Referer'] = login.url + '/' + dsn['dsn']

    # Query the JSON endpoint for the data that we actually want
    data = s.post('https://www.wifi.ecowater.com/Dashboard/UpdateFrequentData', data=dsn, headers=headers)
    print(data.json())
```